# How can I insert nil or blank text field with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

- Elixir1.6
- Phoenix 1.3
- Mysql 5.5

On MySQL, I set text column nullable. However when I use ecto to insert null or blank value. It cause error. 
How can I handle null(nil) or blank value into text field with ecto?

Are there any specification inserting into text field does not work?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I can’t catch any error on display. I just know it goes {:error,} not {:ok, } part. How can I retrieve error detail?

Comment: If I set value which is not null(nil) or blank, the insert goes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. In the model module, validate_required method cause this.
It was not error, just validated by phoenix framework.

```
def changeset(%Model{} = model, attrs) do
  model
  |> cast(attrs, [:param1, :param2, :param3])
  |> validate_required([:param1, :param2, :param3])
end
```

If param3 is nil, it should be like this.

```
def changeset(%Model{} = model, attrs) do
  model
  |> cast(attrs, [:param1, :param2, :param3])
  |> validate_required([:param1, :param2])
end
```

Just my easy mistake.